jquery get the main css value not the current @media/mobile value
I hardly post as I can normally find the answer but I have been searching for hours and my head feels like its going to pop.... anyway
I am looking to get the css values for the "Desktop" version of a css element but I dont want the @media/responsive values, for example
.my-css {

  font-weight: 400; /* Desktop version */

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 724px) {

    .my-css {

      font-weight: 200; /* responsive version */

    }
}

Now I want my jquery to get the Desktop version NOT the responsive version, so even of the responsive version is the current screen version I still want the value of the desktop version, so
var FontWeight = $('.my-css').css('font-weight'); /* 400 NOT 200 */

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you in advance

One (no jquery) option is traversing document.styleSheets (it's a simplified version, invest in learning deeper)


for (let sheet of document.styleSheets)
  for (let i of sheet.cssRules)
    if (i.selectorText === '.my-css')
      console.log(i.style.fontWeight)
.my-css {
  font-weight: 900;
  /* Desktop version */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 724px) {
  .my-css {
    font-weight: 200;
    /* responsive version */
  }
}
<i class="my-css">XOXO</i>



Another option is using css variables


console.log(
  $('.my-css').css('--desktop-font-weight')
)
.my-css {
  --desktop-font-weight: 900;
  --mobile-font-weight: 200;

  font-weight: var(--desktop-font-weight);
  /* Desktop version */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 724px) {
  .my-css {
    font-weight: var(--mobile-font-weight);
    /* responsive version */
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="my-css">XOXO</i>




Thank you so much for the help, I ended up going for the first option as a lot of the css I need is done with a page builder and I didnt fancy creating a new css override.
